# script to copy/paste rss feed file from remote location to my server

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to run a cronjob from my server which pulls the rss feed file from a remote location and copy to my server. So that the rss feed file in my server will be up-to-date as of that in remote.

But the cronjob is a simple one. I cant create/run a cronjob from command, Instead I can schedule the cronjob for my domain by selecting the time/day and the file to use for that cronjob, so that it trigger file at the scheduled time. The php code in that file will do the rest. But dont know how to make the script to pull rss feed from a remote url to my server with that. Do you have an idea/script for this to work.

**I mean to say that I want to copy and paste the fresh copy of rss feed file from remote server to my server location by replacing the old file if any and this process goes on in my each schedule**

**I am not suppose to pull the content items from the rss feed instead I want the file copy/paste**

Comment: just need to get the contents of the rss?

Comment: see xmlReader , cUrl on php.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have remote URL enabled for `fopen()` wrappers, then it is rather easy.

Your cron PHP file will look something like this...

```
<?php

// If you are running via CLI, deny all non CLI requests
if (PHP_SAPI !== 'cli') {
    exit;
}

$remoteFeed = 'http://example.com/feed.rss';

$feed = file_get_contents($remoteFeed);

if ($feed !== FALSE) {  

    file_put_contents('feed.rss', $feed);

}
```

Your file `feed.rss` should be a copy of the remote file. If there is an error getting the remote file, your local copy will not be updated. If the remote server responds with a blank response body, it *will* be updated.

If you don't have `allow_fopen_url` on, then you will need to use cURL.

Comment: I tried this code in my local wamp but nothing is happening. Is that because I am in my local server. I change the $remotefeed URL to my rss feed...but nothing is happening

Comment: @Rahul Remove the check for CLI and then access it directly - see if it creates the file.